# Python script stopping after a while

Tags: python, linux, crash, cron, debian

I have a raspberry pi with raspbian on it, and I've created a python script that I need to have running all the time. The problem is that after running for an hour or so, the script suddenly stops, and the python process shuts down. I have no idea why, and I'm very new to linux so I don't know how to debug it or anything. I don't think it's a memory issue because during the while loop I free and reinit all objects used. How can I find out what the issue is, or at least automatically restart the program once it stops?

This is the code:

```
import time
import sys
import ftputil
import pygame
import pygame.camera
import logging

pygame.camera.init()
#pygame.camera.list_camera() #Camera detected or not
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(640,480))
count = 5
logging.basicConfig(filename='log.log', level=logging.INFO)
logging.info(str(time.time())+" : Script was started")

while True:
        cam.start()
        img = cam.get_image()
        pygame.image.save(img,"current.jpeg")
        cam.stop()
        host = ftputil.FTPHost(**)
        host.upload("./current.jpeg", "/domains/*/public_html/webcam.jpg", mode='b')
        host.close()
        if not count:
                host = ftputil.FTPHost(**)
                filename = str(time.time()) + ".jpg"
                host.upload("./current.jpeg", "/webcamarchive/"+filename, mode='b')
                host.close()
                count = 10
                logging.info(str(time.time())+": Still running")
        count -= 1
        time.sleep(3)
```

I run the script from ssh. But I would like to make it start when the computer starts up, as well, how would I do this?

Comment: Are you running the script as a user in the bash shell?

Comment: Is there anything in your syslogs, either from the script, or about the process?

Comment: Also, you have absolutely no error handling here. Are you sure that none of the functions you call, like `cam.get_image()` or `host.upload()` or whatever, could possibly raise an exception?

Comment: Finally, I'm pretty sure this isn't your actual code, because `if !count:` is a `SyntaxError` in Python. Obscuring the `FTPHost` params is fine (although testing to see whether it's relevant, and completely removing all the FTP stuff if you can still repro the problem without it, would be even better). But as much as possible, try to post code that actually runs and exhibits the problem you're trying to test.

Comment: The ! was a last minute change, I didn't test it, I just assumed that's how you wrote it in python, I'm not used to that language. Also, as said I am very new to linux, how can I check the syslogs? And no, I'm not sure those functions can't raise an exception, but I don't really know how to check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's not worry about getting it to run every time your computer starts up until you can get it to run continuously in a normal login session.

If you're `ssh`ing into the computer and starting it, just leave the `ssh` session open, and watch what it prints out. If you can't do that for whatever reason, capture the output by doing, e.g., `python foo.py >foo.out 2>foo.err` instead of just `python.py`. Either way, you'll be able to see *why* it's stopped, instead of just knowing that it's stopped.

You should also look at the `log.log` file that you explicitly create in your code, and at the syslogs (`/var/log/syslog` by default on most linux distros), to see if there's anything relevant there.

Also, please tell us exactly *how* you're "run[ning] the script from ssh". If you're backgrounding it with `&`, sending it as the `ssh` command, etc., the instructions above need to be modified. (But you don't have to wait for the modified version—just this once, `ssh` into a normal login script, run it without backgrounding, and leave it running.)

With only the information that you've given us so far, it's impossible to know exactly what's going on. But my first guess is that you're getting an unhandled exception, which you'd see as an exception traceback, something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exc.py", line 7, in <module>
    foo()
  File "exc.py", line 5, in foo
    print(1/x)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

The fix is to handle it. The most trivial fix is something like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        cam.start()
        img = cam.get_image()
        pygame.image.save(img,"current.jpeg")
        cam.stop()
        host = ftputil.FTPHost(**)
        host.upload("./current.jpeg", "/domains/*/public_html/webcam.jpg", mode='b')
        host.close()
        if !count:
                host = ftputil.FTPHost(**)
                filename = str(time.time()) + ".jpg"
                host.upload("./current.jpeg", "/webcamarchive/"+filename, mode='b')
                host.close()
                count = 10
                logging.info(str(time.time())+": Still running")
        count -= 1
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Caught exception: ' + str(e))
    time.sleep(3)
```

However, you're probably better off looking over each kind of exception you could run into—or looking at the exception you actually *are* running into—and putting the appropriate error handling and logging in each place, and only using this as a last-ditch fallback.

Also, you should really use `with` clauses instead of manual `close` calls. For example, if `host.upload()` raises, the `host.close()` will never get called. So, instead of this:

```
host = ftputil.FTPHost(**)
host.upload("./current.jpeg", "/domains/*/public_html/webcam.jpg", mode='b')
host.close()
```

Do this:

```
with contextlib.closing(ftputil.FTPHost(**)) as host:
    host.upload("./current.jpeg", "/domains/*/public_html/webcam.jpg", mode='b')
```

(Many types don't even need the `closing`, because they're already inherently context managers, so try that first—but if you get an error about `ftputil.FTPHost` not having an `__enter__` or `__exit__`, this is how you can deal with it.)

Comment: Thanks, as you can see I am very new to this language, I didn't even know about "with" and "try". I will try this and report back