# Process will automatic stop running after one hours in Python

Tags: python

I am using python to send email to multiple receivers according to the excel file. However, the process will auto-stop running after its is running one hours plus.

May I know what is the root caused and how to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python script stopping after a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998496/python-script-stopping-after-a-while)

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you. Did it print out anything when it stopped? Are you catching exceptions? I would look at the first row of the excel file where it didn’t send an email and see if there is something unexpected about it that caused your program to have an error

Comment: Are you running this on a shared web hosting service?  Many of them automatically kill long-running processes.

Comment: @LouFranco Have include exception in my script. Due to there may have some of the receivers didn't have email, therefore, will need to skip it and process to the next receiver.

Comment: @TimRoberts How will it considered as shared web hosting service? I m using python to access the gmail to send out the email. Is gmail as a shared web hosting service?

Comment: WHERE are you running this?  Are you running this process on your own computer?  Or is it on a cloud server somewhere?

Comment: From my own laptop